# C++ Templates: correct way to return a new type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Sorry for the generic title, but I'm unable to focus the problem.

I have a templatized class method that accept an argument pack and provides a new type in return, to hide the details of the implementation. More specifically, the class handles SQLite queries, and the method calls `sqlite3_prepare()` to prepare the statement before executing the query.

```
class Table {
   ...
   template <typename ...Ts>
   class PreparedStatement { ... };

   template <typename ...Ts>
   PreparedStatement<Ts...> prepare(std::tuple<Ts...> tuple) {
      // do something
      return PreparedStatement<Ts...> ( ... );
   }
```

That works well with "normal" types, but the problem occurs when the arguments are declared `const`:

```
const Field<int> fld = createField<int>("name");
...
PreparedStatement<decltype(fld)> s = prepare(make_tuple(fld));
```

The error is the following:

```
no match for 'operator =' (operand types are PreparedStatenent<const Field<int>> and PreparedStatement<Field<int>>
```

I suspect the issue is in my declaration of the function, is there a way to fix this issue and make the function more "elegant" ?

**NOTE**: I know I can fix the issue by manually declare the `s` variable, but my doubts are on how the method was implemented.

---

As Many Asked, here's an example:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct Field {
};

class Table {
public:
   template <typename ...Ts>
   class PreparedStatement {
       public:
       PreparedStatement() {};
    };

   template <typename ...Ts>
   PreparedStatement<Ts...> prepare(std::tuple<Ts...> tuple) {
      // do something
      return PreparedStatement<Ts...> ( );
   }
};


int main() 
{
    Field<int> fld;  
    Table t;

    Table::PreparedStatement<decltype(fld)> p;
    p = t.prepare(std::make_tuple(fld));

    // here comes the problem
    const Field<int> f2;
    Table::PreparedStatement<decltype(f2)> p2;

    p2 = t.prepare(std::make_tuple(f2));    

    return 0;
}
```

and here's the compiler output

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:35:39: error: no match
>   for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Table::PreparedStatement >' and 'Table::PreparedStatement >')
>        p2 = t.prepare(std::make_tuple(f2));
>                                          ^ main.cpp:10:10: note: candidate: constexpr Table::PreparedStatement >&
>   Table::PreparedStatement >::operator=(const
>   Table::PreparedStatement >&)
>       class PreparedStatement {
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ main.cpp:10:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Table::PreparedStatement >'
>   to 'const Table::PreparedStatement >&'
>   main.cpp:10:10: note: candidate: constexpr
>   Table::PreparedStatement >&
>   Table::PreparedStatement
>
> > ::operator=(Table::PreparedStatement >&&) main.cpp:10:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from
> >     'Table::PreparedStatement >' to
> >     'Table::PreparedStatement >&&'

**UPDATE**
As many noted, I could use `auto` to deduce the type, but in some condition `auto` cannot practically be used. One is, for example, if I need to declare the statement in the Class Context.
So suppose `auto` is forbidden for some reason. Isn't any other solution available? See the updated code above.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], `typename Ts...` is not valid C++ syntax,

Comment: I don't see any use of `operator=` in your example, either.

Comment: Neither is the return type of `prepare()` without template parameters.

Comment: An appropriate invocation of `std::remove_const`, or `std::remove_const_t` would likely be the answer, but this is obviously fake code and without a [mcve], trying to put together an answer would likely to be a waste of time.

Comment: `auto s = prepare(make_tuple(fld));`

Comment: Of course this is a nice solution, but what if I can't use auto, for example, because I need to declare `s` as a member in a `pImpl` pattern? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

cppreference.com for [make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) tells us:

> `template< class... Types >
>   tuple<VTypes...> make_tuple( Types&&... args );`
>
> For each `Ti` in `Types...`, the corresponding type `Vi` in `Vtypes...` is
>   `std::decay<Ti>::type` unless application of `std::decay` results in
>   `std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced
>   type is `X&`.

While `std::decay`, among other things, removes cv-qualifiers. So your type will be no `PreparedStatement<const Field<int>>`, but `PreparedStatement<Field<int>>`.

You can use `auto`, as manni66 proposed, to avoid such problems.

```
auto s = prepare(make_tuple(fld));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could use auto to deduce the type, but in some condition auto cannot practically be used. One is, for example, if I need to declare the statement in the Class Context. So suppose auto is forbidden for some reason. Isn't any other solution available? See the updated code above.

Instead of `auto`, you can use a `decltype` expression that take in count the value returned by `prepare`.

I mean... instead of

```
Table::PreparedStatement<decltype(f2)> p2;
```

you can try with

```
decltype(t.prepare(std::make_tuple(f2))) p2;
```

or

```
decltype(std::declval<Table>().prepare(
   std::make_tuple(std::declval<Field<int>>()))) p2;
```

I suppose you can use a similar `decltype()` also to declare members of your classes.